# Colloquial way of saying 'I choose'

Tags: phrase-request

If someone asks me

> Does 8:30 am work for you for the meeting, or should have it 2 in the afernoon?

I want to say, of these two options **I choose** the 2pm one. What is the colloquial word/expression of saying I choose or I select?

Comment: Probably in the interests of politeness, we don't normally use any variant of *"I xxxx option X"*. We tend to say things like *"X would be fine [by me]"*. Explicitly saying what *you* choose implies you're appropriating the choice to yourself, whereas one is normally concerned to make it sound more like a mutually-agreed consensus in such contexts.

Comment: And since you've already used "*work for someone*" in the question, the reply *in kind* would be:  "*Two o'clock works for me.*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways one might indicate which time is best:

> 8:30 sounds good.
>
> Let's go with 8:30.
>
> How about 8:30.
>
> 8:30 works.
>
> 8:30 would be fine.

I would avoid saying *I choose 8:30* for the reasons FumbleFingers has mentioned. *I would prefer 8:30* is more polite, but I would probably use the above forms instead.

Comment: +1, noting as Jim did that "8:30 works" would be the appropriate response to the form "Does 8:30 *work*?"

Answer (score 4):

The most common one (particularly in business English) is *I'll go with*, or *we'll go with* if the decision is for more than one person.

> **Let's go with** having the meeting at 4. That way we can leave early if the meeting is short.
>
> **I'm going to go** with the chilli-mayo dip, please.
>
> **We went with** a green cover for the document, because we felt that best represented the company's values

Note that with the exception of the past-tense form (eg *we went with green because it matches the company logo*), "go with" is very informal for use in formal writing.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option is *I would prefer X*.

> Would you like coffee or tea?
> *I would prefer* coffee, please.
>
> Would you like meet at 8:30 or 2 in the afternoon?
> *I would prefer* 2 o'clock as I have another appointment in the morning.

Note that *prefer* is quite soft word. It suggests that any option is fine for you, in general, but you have reasons to *choose* a certain one. If you state your reasons, it would become obvious that another option is **not** actually fine for you. Anyway, using a polite expression is never wrong.

Also, if neither option is good for you, *I would **rather*** is the way to go:

> Would you like meet at 8:30 or 2 in the afternoon?
> *I would **rather*** meet tomorrow as I'm not in the city today.

Comment: Not sure that *rather prefer* together means what you intend.  You might say, "I'd rather meet tomorrow."  But *rather prefer* means that your preference is set, seemingly against your will, and you would like to have your preference be something different than it is.

Comment: @Jim Good point. Is it the same in all variants of English (US, UK)?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @bytebuster I imagine it's true universally.  The phrase "rather prefer" doesn't make sense in this context, at least to me.  I think it might be possible to construct a context where it *does* make sense, but I just tried and couldn't come up with one.